# Connecting SQL Server on one network to another by using SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms

I want to connect to SQL Server on another network. I have performed the following steps on SQL Server Management Studio but have not been able to achieve the final result:

1. Enabled TCP/IP
2. TCP Port to 1433
3. After changing the TCP properties, restarted the SQL Server Service
4. SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) start mode as Automatic
5. Rule Type: Port 
   While testing connectivity, my connection failed. What could be the reason of it? I have followed the following link:
   https://paulgrevink.wordpress.com/2014/02/06/resolving-ms-sql-remote-connection-issues-i/

Comment: when you say its on another network how do you connect to this second network?

Comment: @MangalPardeshi After performing all these steps, I received an error: "Test Connection Failed"